# django links to the comment function in the backend does not work

Tags: django, comments

After transfer the website to another server with higher python version stoped working the links in the backend to the comment function. Does somebody know where could the problem be? Thank you.

I´m using django 1.6 (I hope I could update it soon)

This is code in the ***settings.py*** on the root level (only the important parts)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.syndication',
    'django_comments',
    'blog',
    'hyper',
    'webmanager',
    'watson',
)
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_summernote', )


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'webmanager.middleware.MyPageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
SITE_ID='1'
#WSGI_APPLICATION = 'marxelhino.wsgi.application'


# fluent-comments settings:
    FLUENT_COMMENTS_USE_EMAIL_MODERATION = True
    FLUENT_COMMENTS_MODERATE_AFTER_DAYS = 14
    FLUENT_COMMENTS_CLOSE_AFTER_DAYS = 60
    FLUENT_COMMENTS_AKISMET_ACTION = 'moderate'
    AKISMET_API_KEY = None # Add your Akismet key here to enable Akismet support
    AKISMET_IS_TEST = True # for development/example apps.
```

This is the code I have in the ***urls.py*** on the root level

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    from marxelhino.feeds import Latest
    # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^$', 'marxelinho.views.home', name='home'),
        url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index', name='index'),
        url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$$', 'blog.views.detail', name='detail'),
        url(r'^blog/by_year/(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'blog.views.post_year', name='list-years'),
        url(r'^blog/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/$', 'blog.views.post_month', name='list-month'),
        url(r'^blog/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/$', 'blog.views.post_day', name='list-day'),
        url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_./-]+)/$$', 'blog.views.category_detail', name='category_detail'),
        #url(r'^blog/comments/', include('fluent_comments.urls')),
        url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),
        (r'^latest/feed/$', Latest()),
        url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
        url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')),
        url(r'^summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
        url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
        # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
         url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
       # (r'^suche/', include('haystack.urls')),
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

the code in ***urls.py*** in the folder ***django_comments***

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('django_comments.views',
    url(r'^post/$',          'comments.post_comment',       name='comments-post-comment'),
    url(r'^posted/$',        'comments.comment_done',       name='comments-comment-done'),
    url(r'^flag/(\d+)/$',    'moderation.flag',             name='comments-flag'),
    url(r'^flagged/$',       'moderation.flag_done',        name='comments-flag-done'),
    url(r'^delete/(\d+)/$',  'moderation.delete',           name='comments-delete'),
    url(r'^deleted/$',       'moderation.delete_done',      name='comments-delete-done'),
    url(r'^approve/(\d+)/$', 'moderation.approve',          name='comments-approve'),
    url(r'^approved/$',      'moderation.approve_done',     name='comments-approve-done'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^cr/(\d+)/(.+)/$', 'django.contrib.contenttypes.views.shortcut', name='comments-url-redirect'),
)
```

and this code is in the folder ***fluent_comments*** and in the file ***views.py***

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib import comments
from django.contrib.comments import signals
from django.contrib.comments.views.comments import CommentPostBadRequest
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from fluent_comments import appsettings
import json


@csrf_protect
@require_POST
def post_comment_ajax(request, using=None):
    """
    Post a comment, via an Ajax call.
    """
    if not request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Expecting Ajax call")

    # This is copied from django.contrib.comments.
    # Basically that view does too much, and doesn't offer a hook to change the rendering.
    # The request object is not passed to next_redirect for example.
    #
    # This is a separate view to integrate both features. Previously this used django-ajaxcomments
    # which is unfortunately not thread-safe (it it changes the comment view per request).


    # Fill out some initial data fields from an authenticated user, if present
    data = request.POST.copy()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if not data.get('name', ''):
            data["name"] = request.user.get_full_name() or request.user.username
        if not data.get('email', ''):
            data["email"] = request.user.email

    # Look up the object we're trying to comment about
    ctype = data.get("content_type")
    object_pk = data.get("object_pk")
    if ctype is None or object_pk is None:
        return CommentPostBadRequest("Missing content_type or object_pk field.")
    try:
        object_pk = long(object_pk)
        model = models.get_model(*ctype.split(".", 1))
        target = model._default_manager.using(using).get(pk=object_pk)
    except ValueError:
        return CommentPostBadRequest("Invalid object_pk value: {0}".format(escape(object_pk)))
    except TypeError:
        return CommentPostBadRequest("Invalid content_type value: {0}".format(escape(ctype)))
    except AttributeError:
        return CommentPostBadRequest("The given content-type {0} does not resolve to a valid model.".format(escape(ctype)))
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return CommentPostBadRequest("No object matching content-type {0} and object PK {1} exists.".format(escape(ctype), escape(object_pk)))
    except (ValueError, ValidationError) as e:
        return CommentPostBadRequest("Attempting go get content-type {0!r} and object PK {1!r} exists raised {2}".format(escape(ctype), escape(object_pk), e.__class__.__name__))

    # Do we want to preview the comment?
    preview = "preview" in data

    # Construct the comment form
    form = comments.get_form()(target, data=data)

    # Check security information
    if form.security_errors():
        return CommentPostBadRequest("The comment form failed security verification: {0}".format)

    # If there are errors or if we requested a preview show the comment
    if preview:
        comment = form.get_comment_object() if not form.errors else None
        return _ajax_result(request, form, "preview", comment, object_id=object_pk)
    if form.errors:
        return _ajax_result(request, form, "post", object_id=object_pk)


    # Otherwise create the comment
    comment = form.get_comment_object()
    comment.ip_address = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR", None)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        comment.user = request.user

    # Signal that the comment is about to be saved
    responses = signals.comment_will_be_posted.send(
        sender  = comment.__class__,
        comment = comment,
        request = request
    )

    for (receiver, response) in responses:
        if response is False:
            return CommentPostBadRequest("comment_will_be_posted receiver {0} killed the comment".format(receiver.__name__))

    # Save the comment and signal that it was saved
    comment.save()
    signals.comment_was_posted.send(
        sender  = comment.__class__,
        comment = comment,
        request = request
    )

    return _ajax_result(request, form, "post", comment, object_id=object_pk)


def _ajax_result(request, form, action, comment=None, object_id=None):
    # Based on django-ajaxcomments, BSD licensed.
    # Copyright (c) 2009 Brandon Konkle and individual contributors.
    #
    # This code was extracted out of django-ajaxcomments because
    # django-ajaxcomments is not threadsafe, and it was refactored afterwards.

    success = True
    json_errors = {}

    if form.errors:
        for field_name in form.errors:
            field = form[field_name]
            json_errors[field_name] = _render_errors(field)
        success = False

    json_return = {
        'success': success,
        'action': action,
        'errors': json_errors,
        'object_id': object_id,
        'use_threadedcomments': bool(appsettings.USE_THREADEDCOMMENTS),
    }

    if comment is not None:
        context = {
            'comment': comment,
            'action': action,
            'preview': (action == 'preview'),
            'USE_THREADEDCOMMENTS': appsettings.USE_THREADEDCOMMENTS,
        }
        comment_html = render_to_string('comments/comment.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        json_return.update({
            'html': comment_html,
            'comment_id': comment.id,
            'parent_id': None,
            'is_moderated': not comment.is_public,   # is_public flags changes in comment_will_be_posted
        })
        if appsettings.USE_THREADEDCOMMENTS:
            json_return['parent_id'] = comment.parent_id

    json_response = json.dumps(json_return)
    return HttpResponse(json_response, content_type="application/json")


def _render_errors(field):
    """
    Render form errors in crispy-forms style.
    """
    template = '{0}/layout/field_errors.html'.format(appsettings.CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK)
    return render_to_string(template, {
        'field': field,
        'form_show_errors': True,
    })
```

and this code in the folder ***fluent_comments*** and in the file ***urls.py***

```
try:
    # Django 1.6 requires this
    from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include
except ImportError:
    # Django 1.3 compatibility, kept in minor release
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import url, patterns, include


urlpatterns = patterns('fluent_comments.views',
    url(r'^post/ajax/$', 'post_comment_ajax', name='comments-post-comment-ajax'),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
)
```

Comment: It's in line 7.

Comment: Hey friend, can you share your code, project config, etc. Give us info to help you